# How to extend an @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

This is my superclass

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
@Component
@Inheritance
public class Utente implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7124540331184173742L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z 'òàùèéì]*$")      
    @NotBlank
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "cognome")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z 'òàùèéì]*$")
    @NotBlank
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "utente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    private Autenticazione autenticazione;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utente", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    private List<Autorizzazioni> autorizzazioniLista;
}
```

This is the class that extend the one above:

```
@Entity
public class UtenteSubClass extends Utente{ 

@Transient
private String newField;
}
```

When I try to retrieve an object **UtenteSubClass**  I get this error `"org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Unknown column 'this_.DTYPE' in 'where clause'"`.

Probably my "mapping system" is wrong. Where is my error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it looks like you didn't re-generate your table structure after editing your code. Set the option ``hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`` to ``update`` in your ``persistence.xml`` and run it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose to use `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance (which is default for `@Inheritance` annotation without arguments in your code) then you should add `@DiscriminatorColumn` annotation to your superclass (and `@DiscriminatorValue` to extending classes). Otherwise via [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html):

> If @DiscriminatorColumn is not specified on the root of the entity hierarchy and a discriminator column is required, the Persistence provider assumes a default column name of DTYPE and column type of DiscriminatorType.STRING.

hibernate just can't find this default column in your table. You can introduce your own descriminator column, or generate default one

Comment: By default the SINGLE_TABLE is used and the column name is DTYPE and it type is String.

Comment: I did by writing "@Inheritance", didn't I?

Comment: Thanks man, now it works, what I missed were @DiscriminatorColumn and the relative field on the table.

Comment: you're welcome! That's why we all love stackoverflow =)